# Not able to convert image to binary format to store it into text file

Tags: c#, winforms, filestream

I'm trying to convert the image to binary format by using `FileStream` object as well as `File.WriteAllBytes` but the text file is empty. Attached the code below.

```
string fname,sfname; FileStream fsrw; byte[] bytearray;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnbrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        fname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = fname;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        sfname = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        fsrw = new FileStream(sfname, FileMode.Open);
        bytearray = new Byte[fsrw.Length];
        fsrw.Read(bytearray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fsrw.Length));
        MessageBox.Show("success");
        File.write
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint and check the execution the `fsrw` has the the file in it and when I hover over the `bytearray` it gives `byte[300127]` and its all zeros in the array.

Comment: what binary format? Do you actually just want to copy the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the image item when you do the following line:

```
fsrw.Read(bytearray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fsrw.Length));
```

In fact, your never set the bytearray so it's 0 valued. And *fsrw* is your output stream, not your input.

If I understand your code, your image file (input) is located at *fname*, so you should do:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Select the output file
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    sfname = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    // Create an output stream with this file
    fsrw = new FileStream(sfname, FileMode.Open);

    // Read your image
    bytearray = File.ReadAllBytes(fname);

    // Write the array to the outputStream
    fsrw.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
    fsrw.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("success");
}
```

If you need to save your picture into a new file, just change this method (set the sfname string with the location) and change the `new FileStream(sfname, FileMode.Open);` in a new `FileStream(sfname, FileMode.Create);`

Comment: And what the following code do: `fsrw.Read(bytearray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fsrw.Length));` ?

Comment: In his code it's reading the file from fsrw (which is his output file!) to store the content in the bytearray (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The mistake is between reading and writing in his code

Comment: You're welcome. That's also why I added comments on the different process phases in my response, to clearly see what is about reading and what is about writing

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this it is working for me

```
    var sfname = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    FileStream stream = new FileStream(sfname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream );

    byte[] image = br.ReadBytes((int)stream .Length);

    br.Close();

    stream .Close();
```

Comment: what variable to use after stream as i'm getting System.IO.Stream is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'